# Как получить картинку с другого сайта? Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть url страницы сайта, как c данной страницы можно получить картинку с id "image"? Допустим, что url: www.images.com/myImage. Без использования серверных ЯПов.

Answer (score 0):

Если не запрещает [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), то с помощью jquery можно как-то так:

```
$.get('a.html', null, function (text) {
    console.log($(text).find('#name'))
});
```

На чистом js:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    console.log(event)
}, false)

request.open('GET', 'a.html', true)
request.send()
```

Это самый легкий путь.